# How to avoid an extra space on the right while creating a navigation bar using flexbox (justify-content: space-between/around) properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGsNd.png)I got stack by a simple thing...
I am trying to create a simple navigation for my footer. So, I created a  and placed an  in it. The list contains three

s and each of them has an  inside. I wish my list items to be placed horizontally with spaces between / around them. Thus, I decided to use flexbox in this case. The question is that when I am setting display property value of my  to flex and justify-content to center, it work predictably (i.e. all the list items sticked to each other are centered horizontally), however, as soon as I set justify-content to "space-between" or "space-around" I get an extra space to the right side of my content, which makes this space three times bigger than the one on the left side of the content. 
I tried to search this topic in the history, but found nothing similar. Google search brought me a potential solution - to set flex:1 to each of the list items. But in this case I loose the gaps between the items which is not my intention.
Below I provide a picture of the problem and my testing code snippets. One more observation is that everything works great in code snippets programs (JSFiddle or Code Pen)...
[Problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKKb6.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.footer {
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30vh;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.list {
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  min-width: 30%;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="item"><a href="">1</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="">2</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: from your snippet it looks like everything is ok

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am saying - due to some reason this code does not work properly in my localhost

Comment: Why do you have an `absolute` position? In the image, you got a _clearfix_ solution with the `::after` pseudo-element, which can mess up things in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is ok. In your screenshot it seems you have a lot more css going on, though.

I can't see the complete CSS-snippet in your screenshot and I might be completely wrong: It looks like a piece of the clearfix-hack where you are missing the ::before part.
Because adding an empty space only in ::after will have exactly the effect you are describing.
It probably is the remains of a former float-construct, so you can just remove the ::after part.